# how can use Current Date Time code in php

Tags: php, date, time

how can show current date and time in PHP in text fields i am using this code for current date and time for zone(India) ....but now show current date and time

```
 <tr>
<td height="24"><div align="right"><strong>Last&nbsp;Signon&nbsp;DTTM:</strong></div></td>
<td><input type="text"  readonly=""name="LASTSIGNONDTTM" style="background:#CCCCCC"  
value="<?php echo date('d-M-Y, H:i A'); ?>"/></td>           
</tr>
```

Comment: Instead of `'d-M-Y'` use `'d-M-Y H:i:s'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this for india time zone

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
    echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s'); //Returns IST
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Date and Time you need to change `d-M-Y` to `d-m-Y H:i:s`

```
<input type="text" name="LASTSIGNONDTTM" style="background:#CCCCCC"  
value="<?php echo date("d-m-Y H:i:s"); ?>" readonly />
```

Also if you are not getting current date of India so add indian timezone at the top...

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
?>
```

[Date Manual](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
echo date("d-M-Y H:i:s");
```

To know more see [Date() manual](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Code:

First Set Time Format in PHP then use date function.

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
echo date("d-m-Y H:i:s"); // use this in value attribute of textbox

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is what you are looking for!

Try this...

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York")
echo "Today is " . date("d-m-Y") . "<br>";
echo "The time is " . date("h:i:sa");
?>
```